# Craft not loading custom 404 template for errors

Tags: templating, 404, 404-page

Whenever I hit a non-existent page on a dev site, I only get Craft's native 404 page, not the one I have at `/craft/templates/404.html`. The site has no routes. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the `general.php` file had the following line ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#errorTemplatePrefix)) in it:

```
'errorTemplatePrefix' => "_errors/"
```

Once I'd created the proper folder and files, all worked as expected.

Thanks, [@CraftCMS Twitter person](https://twitter.com/CraftCMS/status/967144907541397504)!

Answer (score 5):

It's quite possible that you are in Dev mode. If you switch to `false`, the 404.html may then be recognized…

Look at general.php, then change `devMode` to `false`.

`// Dev environment settings
    'dev' => [
        'devMode' => true,
    ],`

Comment: I certainly am in dev mode; I'm puzzled as to why custom 404 templates would be bypassed in dev mode though. Changing it to `false` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Suggestion: you can drop in your html structure into the 404 template and add `{% extends "_layouts/default.html" %}`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that helps when the entire point of this question is that the 404 template _isn't_ getting loaded in the first place.

Comment: This makes no sense. Why do we have to turn dev mode off to see the 404?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you are in production mode in the **.env** file: `ENVIRONMENT=production`
2. Make sure you have developer mode disabled in **config/general.php** file: `'devMode'=>false`
3. Make sure you have a **404.twig** file in **templates/**
4. This is not necessary, but ff you have all of the above and it still does not work, you can try adding this line in the **config/general.php** file: [`'errorTemplatePrefix' => "404.twig"`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#errortemplateprefix)

You can also always go directly to the template and see if it is working. `http://yourpath.test/404`